# Hive query does not begin MapReduce process after starting job and generating Tracking URL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hadoop-yarn

I'm using Apache Hive.
I created a table in Hive (similar to external table) and loaded data into the same using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './Desktop/loc1/kv1.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE adih;` command.

While I am able to retrieve simple data from the hive table adih (e.g. `select * from adih`, `select c_code from adih limit 1000`, etc), Hive gives me errors when I ask for data involving slight computations (e.g. `select count(*) from adih`, `select distinct(c_code) from adih`).

The Hive cli output is as shown in the following link -

> hive> select distinct add_user from adih;
>
> Query ID = latize_20161031155801_8922630f-0455-426b-aa3a-6507aa0014c6
>
> Total jobs = 1
>
> Launching Job 1 out of 1
>
> Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
>
> In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
>
> set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
>
> In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
>
> set hive.exec.reducers.max=
>
> In order to set a constant number of reducers:
>
> set mapreduce.job.reduces=
>
> Starting Job = job_1477889812097_0006, Tracking URL = http://latize-data1:20005/proxy/application_1477889812097_0006/
>
> Kill Command = /opt/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1477889812097_0006
>
> [6]+  Stopped                 $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive

Hive stops displaying any further logs / actions beyond the last line of "Kill Command"

Not sure where I have gone wrong (many answers on StackOverflow tend to point back to YARN configs (environment config detailed below).
I have the log as well but it contains more than 30000 characters (Stack Overflow limit)

My hadoop environment is configured as follows - 
1 Name Node & 1 Data Node. Each has 20 GB of RAM with sufficient ROM. Have allocated 13 GB of RAM for the **yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb** and **yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb** each with the **mapreduce.map.memory.mb** being set as 4 GB and the **mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb** being set as 12 GB. Number of reducers is currently set to default (-1). Also, Hive is configured to run with a MySQL DB (rather than Derby).

Comment: I noticed that this state only occurs when I run a command involving the 'distinct' command. On using the 'select count' commands, the MapReduce process starts and completes the mapping. However, the Reduce process tends to continuously show a 0% progress and then gets stuck in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the appropriate values to the properties show in your trace,

eg: Edit the properties in hive-site.xml

```
 <property>
<name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
<value>67108864</value></property>
```

Comment: hope you restarted the service after the change made.

Comment: Did that. In fact, even restarting all the hadoop daemons as well after adding the suggestion in hive-site.xml did not help. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have set mapred.reduce.tasks = -1, which makes Hive refer to its config to decide the number of reduce tasks.
You are getting an error as the number of reducers is missing in Hive config.
Try setting it using below command:

Hive> SET mapreduce.job.reduces=XX

As per official documentation: **The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 multiplied by (< no. of nodes > * < no. of maximum containers per node >).**

Comment: Tried this, but didnt work. For my own clarifications - doesn't Hive apply its own heuristic settings to determine the number of reducer ?

Comment: Yes, It applies. But in the problem statement, it was not clear what was the Hive configuration w.r.t reducer and that's the reason I suggested to set this value.

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying the same @vmorusu. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Hive and MR to work - increased the memory configurations for all the processes involved:
Increased the RAM allocated to YARN Scheduler and maximum RAM allocated to the YARN Nodemanager (in yarn-site.xml), alongside increasing the RAM allocated to the Mapper and Reducer (in mapred-site.xml).
Also incorporated parts of the answers by @Sathiyan S and @vmorusu - set the hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer property to 1 GB of data, which directly affects the number of reducers that Hive uses (through application of its heuristic techniques).